# Error Type: Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A0046) Permission denied

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I am getting this error when i try to access an asp website which has been hosted in IIS 5.

Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A0046)
Permission denied
/Site/Initial.asp, line 164

Please let me know what could be is issue???

Comment: Here is a crazy idea, how about you actually show us the code that happens to be on Line 164 of Initial.asp?  I dunno may be there might be clue there.

Comment: yeah sure anthony, i will do that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit IIS Default Web Site Properties.

In the Directory Security tab, make sure the checkbox for user is checked.